# spark 3.0- spark aggregate function gives different expression then expected

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

```
/Downloads/spark-3.0.1-bin-hadoop2.7/bin$ ./spark-shell


20/09/23 10:58:45 WARN Utils: Your hostname, byte-nihal resolves to a loopback address: 127.0.1.1; using 192.168.2.103 instead (on interface enp2s0)
20/09/23 10:58:45 WARN Utils: Set SPARK_LOCAL_IP if you need to bind to another address
20/09/23 10:58:49 WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
Using Spark's default log4j profile: org/apache/spark/log4j-defaults.properties
Setting default log level to "WARN".
To adjust logging level use sc.setLogLevel(newLevel). For SparkR, use setLogLevel(newLevel).
Spark context Web UI available at http://192.168.2.103:4040
Spark context available as 'sc' (master = local[*], app id = local-1600838949311).
Spark session available as 'spark'.
Welcome to
      ____              __
     / __/__  ___ _____/ /__
    _\ \/ _ \/ _ `/ __/  '_/
   /___/ .__/\_,_/_/ /_/\_\   version 3.0.1
      /_/
         
Using Scala version 2.12.10 (OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.8.0_265)
Type in expressions to have them evaluated.
Type :help for more information.

scala> import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

scala> println(countDistinct("x"))
count(x)

scala> println(sumDistinct("x"))
sum(DISTINCT x)

scala> println(sum("x"))
sum(x)

scala> println(count("x"))
count(x)
```

**Question:**

- for sumDistinct expression ->  sum(DISTINCT x)
- but for countDistinct expression -> count(x)

**Is this some kind of bug or the functionality?**

[spark 3.0 doc](https://spark.apache.org/releases/spark-release-3-0-0.html)

> note: countDistinct gives correct expression -> count( Distinct x ) in spark version < 3.0

Comment: It could be related to how `countDistinct` is implemented, see [here](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/functions.scala#L396). It needs to allow for multiple input columns as well as `"*"` while `sum` and `sumDistinct` only works on a single column at the time. In particular, note that the `UnresolvedFunction` in `countDistinct` is named `count`, maybe this is the reason?

Comment: @Shaido it was implemented same in 2.4 spark

Comment: No, the 2.4 version looks like [this](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/e1e94ed4ef45ef81814f1b920bac0afa52ae06a2/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/functions.scala#L391). No use of `UnresolvedFunction`. The change came with this merge which was made to allow for `"*"` inputs: https://github.com/apache/spark/pull/24482

Comment: ok my bad. its implemented differently  [link](https://github.com/zequnyu9503/spark-2.4.4/blob/master/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/functions.scala)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @Shaido mentioned in the comment section... I Have verified few things to point out that there is some bug in the latest version of spark code in toString. (it may be a bug or feature I'm not completely sure)

spark code version < 3.X behaviour

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

println(countDistinct("x")) ---> gives output as  count(x)
```

if we particularly check source code of countDistinct("x")

```
  def countDistinct(columnName: String, columnNames: String*): Column =
    countDistinct(Column(columnName), columnNames.map(Column.apply) : _*)
 
  def countDistinct(expr: Column, exprs: Column*): Column = {
    withAggregateFunction(Count.apply((expr +: exprs).map(_.expr)), isDistinct = true)
  }
```

as you can see in the second overloaded method **Count.apply** aggregate function is used and **isDistinct=true**  to count as distinct values

```
private def withAggregateFunction(
    func: AggregateFunction,
    isDistinct: Boolean = false): Column = {
    Column(func.toAggregateExpression(isDistinct))
  }
```

if you particularly check **withAggregateFunction** signature it returns [Column](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/Column.scala) type and if you check toString method of Column

```
 def toPrettySQL(e: Expression): String = usePrettyExpression(e).sql
```

it call **.sql** method on [AggregateExpression](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/catalyst/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/catalyst/expressions/aggregate/interfaces.scala)

AggregateExpression call back sql method of aggregateFunction as per code below
`override def sql: String = aggregateFunction.sql(isDistinct)`

In our case **AggregateFuncion is Count**.

```
def sql(isDistinct: Boolean): String = {
    val distinct = if (isDistinct) "DISTINCT " else ""
    s"$prettyName($distinct${children.map(_.sql).mkString(", ")})"
  }
```

As per the above code, it should return count(DISTINCT x)

Now, In spark version >= 3.X
I have checked the source code, toString behavior is little different.

```
@scala.annotation.varargs
  def countDistinct(expr: Column, exprs: Column*): Column =
    // For usage like countDistinct("*"), we should let analyzer expand star and
    // resolve function.
    Column(UnresolvedFunction("count", (expr +: exprs).map(_.expr), isDistinct = true))
```

It is now using UnresolvedFunction instead of withAggregateFunction.

In [UnresolvedFunction](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/catalyst/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/catalyst/analysis/unresolved.scala) toString method is pretty straight forward as below

```
override def toString: String = s"'$name(${children.mkString(", ")})"
```

which prints count(x) .. that is why you are getting output as count(x)